# Design approach in MVVM

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

So i want to create a wpf form which shows the ressource planning for each week. The outcome should look like this:

[image]

I'm now struggling with the design of the viewmodel. Let's say I start like this (the child objects are indented):

```
WeekCollection
    Week // (from model)
        ProjectCollection
            Project // (from model)
                DayCollection
                    Day // (from model)
                        EmployeeCollection 
                            Employee // (from model)
```

Where I'm now struggling is, that with this approach, the classes in the model would be expanded to hold information, that is only needed for this particular viewmodel of the weekly planning. I.e. the class for day should have a date property, but not hold a collection for employees.

On the other hand, if I create a seperate viewmodel or a derrived collection class for each collection, wouldn't I get thousands of classes for the whole application?

So the question is, what is the best/usual way, to model the classes in an mvvm application, if the structure is like this?

Comment: If you need functionality at the list level (e.g. `DayCollection`) then you need a new class, if you don't need any additional functionality aside from add/remove and change notification, you can probably just use a built in collection type such as `ObservableCollection<T>`. You can add that as a property to `Week` etc. Most of the time you will find that even though you have more classes, you don't get bogged down when you create a viewmodel for each scenario. The worst situation to be in is with a single monster-class which tries to serve the purpose of viewmodel for many views.

Comment: I somehow have problems with this, because in the long run the project class would hold collections for almost every other class in my application (it is used to manage projects). E.g. collections for bills, employees, days, orders, financial data aso depending on the thins I want to handle. This doesn't seem right from a "lean" modelling view, where the model should only represent the characteristics of said object.

Comment: Yes agreed - you should make multiple versions of the project class - one for each type of view you need where applicable. The more concerns you try to stuff into one viewmodel, the harder it becomes to maintain and the messier your code gets. I've been there before - leaner viewmodels are easier to understand, easier to pick up again when you've been away from your code, easier for others to pick up. Just make sure your project structure has decent conventions for organising these viewmodels.

Comment: I figuered that complex apps somehow always get messy. Maybe its just my lack of experience with mvvm, but it seems to me, that this approach is setting me up for a lot of classes without much chance of reusing them. Anyhow, thank for your answer.

Comment: I recommend reading the following: http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/ - maybe you just need an adjustment to your perspective :)

Comment: You can use microsoft prism.It offers suitable solutions by means of its well-design structure.